# iOS 13 local notification not sending

Tags: uilocalnotification, ios13

I have a reoccurring local notification set up every day at 8am. This has worked completely fine in every iOS except for when I updated to iOS 13+, it no longer sends my local notification. There has been no code changes on that part. I have seen people having issues with push notifications on iOS 13, but this is a local one so I have no idea why it suddenly stopped working on iOS 13. I have tried using xcode 10 & 11.

If anyone needs code posted I can get that, but I'm curious if anyone else has had this issue with local notifications and iOS 13.

Comment: https://onesignal.com/blog/ios-13-introduces-4-breaking-changes-to-notifications/

Comment: That is for push notifications. I am using device tokens or any push notifications. I am just having issues with local notifications.

Comment: I have the same issue with React Native push notifications module. Scheduling notifications are stopped working. Didn't find any solutions to this yet. The same code works good on iOS 12 and older.

Comment: did anyone figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out!

At least for me, setting the trigger with `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` didn't work. However, if I used `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` instead, it works great!

Here's my code:

```swift
let now = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)

// If event has already occured, silently fail.
if (timelineEvent.event.time < now) {
    return
}

// Otherwise, let's calculate the time until the next event
let interval = timelineEvent.event.time.timeIntervalSince(Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0))
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: interval, repeats: false)
```

If you're strictly targeting iOS 13 and newer, the date comparison can be simplified slightly:

```swift
let now = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)

// If event has already occured, silently fail.
if (timelineEvent.event.time < now) {
    return
}

// Otherwise, let's calculate the time until the next event
let interval = now.distance(to: timelineEvent.event.time)
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: interval, repeats: false)
```

Strangely, `Date().distance(to: Date)` appears to be iOS 13+ only, however the documentation says it's available since iOS 7.0.